# How to solve "The type or namespace name 'Systems' does not exist in the namespace 'Fizzler'"?

Tags: c#, fizzler

So I used Nuget to get the Fizzler package and it brought down the HTML agility pack, but now I have a compilation error when trying to use the library

`The type or namespace name 'Systems' does not exist in the namespace 'Fizzler'`

package.config contains

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <packages>
    <package id="Fizzler" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.9.5" targetFramework="net45" />
 </packages>
```

I was trying to call an HTML5 CSS3 selector method `QuerySelectorAll` but it gives error message `... error CS1061: 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'QuerySelectorAll' and no extension method 'QuerySelectorAll' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to use `Fizzer.Systems`? And what does that have to do with the other error you've got? Do you perhaps want `RSA.Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack`?

Comment: Or perhaps https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack/?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I want to use querySelectorAll, [as you no doubt know] it's something JQuery people have been using for years and is now part of HTML5.  I'm expecting this to work out of the box.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:  nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack did not solve.

Comment: You should show the code you did for so see !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite your comment, it looks like you need the `Fizzler.System.HtmlAgilityPack` package. You should then be able to use:

```
using Fizzler.System.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

... at which point the extension methods in `HtmlNodeSelection` (including `QuerySelectorAll`) will be available.

Comment: yep my bad, I did package manager but current selected project was not my real target.